# Is optimistic locking enough to secure operations such as funds transfer?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-core, locking

In the following example we may run into a concurrency error where if the sender decides to send funds to 2 different receivers in the same time then both receivers may get the money while the sender will only be charged once.

```cs
public async Task SendMoney(int amount, int sender, int receiver)
{
    await using var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext();
    
    var person1 = await dbContext.Persons.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == sender);
    var person2 = await dbContext.Persons.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == receiver);
    
    if (person1.Balance >= amount)
    {
        person1.Balance -= amount;
        person2.Balance += amount;
    }
        
    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

What would be the best way to avoid such scenario and make this operation secure?

Is introducing optimistic locking by adding timestamp property `[Timestamp] public byte[] Version { get; set; }` to the `Person` model enough to make sure there is no way of duplicating funds?

I mostly care about the security of avoiding duplication. Properly handling exceptions such as `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` in order to provide smooth user experience is not part of my question.

Comment: Yes, that would ensure consistency

Comment: unless you operate inside a database transaction, there is no guarantee that another application might change your data.

Comment: Why did someone downvote my question? Please, elaborate so I can improve it.

Comment: @MitchWheat Please, clarify. Do you mean that another application may mess with the consistency of the data because it may not implement the same way optimistic locking or may not implement it at all?

Comment: Also - if so, is there any risk left besides it? If we're using this database exclusively for this application, would optimistic locking be enough?

Also, you mentioned database transactions. They're not equal to locks and from what I know - do not prevent race conditions. How would they help?

Thanks.

Comment: "Optimistic" doesn't mean that you fire the thing and forget/pray. It means if an error happens, you'll have to do something (ie: handle errors/exceptions), as opposed to "Pessimistic" where you try to lock everything that must be (which can cost lots in terms of transaction, etc.) *beforehand*, then do it. It's just two ways of doing thing, but the net results is always supposed to be correct (whether it succeeded or failed)

Comment: I am aware of that, @SimonMourier. I even specifically stated that this is not part of my question, though. In this instance all I care about is that data corruption doesn't happen.

Comment: The question "Is optimistic locking enough to secure operations such as funds transfer?" shows you're not that aware

Comment: I agree with @SimonMourier. You don't seem to understand that the whole transfer operation fails if *one* of the Balances changes in the mean time. It's impossible that "both receivers may get the money while the sender will only be charged once." If the sender is charged once only one receiver will actually have received payment. That's the trouble with this question, seemingly it's based on a misconception, and if that's been cleared away the question "is it enough" is still opinion-based.

Comment: Here we get 4 sql queries: two select and two update. Meanwhile, a single update query is enough to perform this operation. PS: EF Core does not allow to do this with only LINQ. Unless with the help of ExecuteSqlRaw method it can be done.

Comment: See [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) - look for "update" term. Some libraries allow you to generate an update sql query without preliminary select query. I'd recommend linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore. Or, even better, switch completely to the linq2db ORM.

Comment: @GertArnold Sorry but I fail to see how you got that out of my question. The race condition I'm describing takes place when there is no locking at all. And I'm asking if setting `[Timestamp]` property is enough to make sure such scenario not occur, so exactly what you described. Failing one of the operations is fine.

Comment: Properly implemented, Optimistic vs Pessimistic has nothing to do with reliability or data integrity, it has to do with whether your transaction conflicts happen at the beginning (preventative) or at the end (corrective).  Data integrity/risk is determined by the isolation level.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Although my question is not necessarily about pesimistic vs optimistic locking, your comment was incredibly useful. Terms such as isolation level directed me to other useful resources. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a concurrent environment `[Timestamp]` will ensure the row is saved only if it was not changed since loaded from DB, so it will work.
Also for the case you have provided, it is possible to set `Balance` field as [Concurrency Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations).

Comment: Extra kudos to you, sir for mentioning Concurrency Token. Fantastic answer.